# Tips for webpage designing

Tags: javascript, css, html

I added a button to open respective information. Then I put all the information in another page. I want to open the selective information in the first of the page when button is clicked of that information.
Is it possible?

I don't want to use jquery.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you tried anything yourself ?

Comment: what you have done so far??

Comment: You can try with XMLHttpRequest (which is pure javascript). For more info, check http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: Do you want to show response of another page to main page after clicking a button?

Answer (score 1):

```
<button onclick="loadInfo()">Get Information</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

so when the user click on that button it will fire the `loadInfo()`function

```
function loadInfo() { 
var xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open("GET", '/path/to/your/respective/information.file',true); //modify this line to your information file path
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
    if(xmlhttp.status==400){
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML= xmlhttp.responseText; //your information will be loaded inside myDiv
            }else{
            console.log('error')}
}
}
xmlhttp.send();
}
```